# Where can the stats at the main bar be changed?

Tags: interface

I would like to hide some of the "mesh info stats". Looked into space_info.py, but it only contains the menu items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are defined in C in `/editors/space_info/info_stats.c`, they are not editable at all from/with python.